# excel - for each cell in X:Y that contains symbol "★" add +1 to cell Z

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried looking up this question or trying to mix other similar formulas I found together to no avail..

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: The countif() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to count the amount of cells in a range (A1:E1) which contain the letter "b":

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND("b",A1:E1)),0,1))
```

The result of `FIND()` is either a location either an error.
The `IF(ISERROR())` translates the error in 0, the non-error in 1. (There is no `ELSE`-clause in the `IFERROR()` function, hence this construction)
The `SUM()` is obvious.

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

So, using countif():

[image]

Then if column AA has the original value, the incremented value would be given by:

```
=AA1+COUNTIF(X1:Y1,"*")
```

If there are other characters surrounding the target character then wildcards work:
[image]